# Create a new list from custom template with CSOM in SharePoint Online

Tags: list-template, csom

I am trying to create a new list from an existing list template using CSOM in a SharePoint Online environment.

Here is my code:

```
using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(WebURL))
{
    ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(UserName, Password);

    var web = ctx.Web;
    var templates = web.ListTemplates;
    ctx.Load(web, s => s.ListTemplates);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    var archiveTemplate = templates.GetByName(ArchiveTemplate);

    ListCreationInformation lic = new ListCreationInformation();
    lic.Title = "New List";
    lic.TemplateFeatureId = archiveTemplate.FeatureId;
    lic.TemplateType = archiveTemplate.ListTemplateTypeKind;
    web.Lists.Add(lic);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

}
```

This results in the following exception

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException was unhandled
>    HResult=-2146233079
>    Message=The property or field 'FeatureId' has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.
>    Source=Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime
>    StackTrace:
>         bei Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientObject.CheckUninitializedProperty(String propName)
>         bei Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListTemplate.get_FeatureId()

I tried to load the properties explicitly by doing the following:

```
 ctx.Load(archiveTemplate, at => at.FeatureId);
 ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

> This results in the following exception:
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException was unhandled
>    HResult=-2146233088
>    Message=Value does not fall within the expected range.
>    Source=Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

After further investigation, it seems as if I need to use the following code to retrieve my custom list template:

```
var templates = ctx.Site.GetCustomListTemplates(web);
ctx.Load(templates);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
var template = templates.First(t => t.Name == ArchiveTemplate);
```

The problem then is that I cannot provide this template within the ListCreationInformation used to add a new list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a list using Client Object Model, it is required to pass a unique "TemplateType" as a parameter. However, there seems no unique "TemplateType" provision for a custom list template, thus, we will not be able to achieve it with the client side API using C# or PowerShell currently.

If it is an on premises environment, Server Object Model can be an option for us as it has the SPWeb.Lists.Add() methodwhich requires no "TemplateType" as parameter.

However, when comes to SharePoint Online, only client side API is allowed.
Thus, I would suggest you submit a feedback to the SharePoint UserVoice Platform if there any expectation about the future version of SharePoint API

Answer (score -1):

This can be done indeed by using a slightly different approach.. We will have to use Site object (site collection) to get the custom templates.. I tried this and it works for me...

```
ListCreationInformation listInfo = new ListCreationInformation();
listInfo.Title = "New List";

ListTemplate listTemplate = ctx.Site.GetCustomListTemplates(ctx.Site.RootWeb).GetByName("Template
   Name");
ctx.Load(listTemplate, tL => tL.Name, tL => tL.FeatureId, tL => tL.ListTemplateTypeKind);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

listInfo.TemplateFeatureId = listTemplate.FeatureId;
listInfo.TemplateType = listTemplate.ListTemplateTypeKind;
web.Lists.Add(listInfo);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: still not working with custom template.